# Connection property set error on registering PostgreSQL geodatabase with ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, postgresql, arcgis-10.2, esri-geodatabase, linux

We're in the middle of a migrating process.

We've imported a geodatabase on a new Linux machine and we're trying to publish some map services to this new ArcGIS Server (that resides on the same machine).

We've upgraded the 10.1 geodatabase to a 10.2 one.

The geodatabase was imported via pgAdmin backup- restore procedure then we used the Upgrade Geodatabase tool from ArcToolbox to go to 10.2.

We've encountered problems when trying to register the geodatabase with the server. 
The error we get is:

> The connection property set was missing a required property or the
>   property value was unrecognized. This release of the GeoDatabase is
>   either invalid or out of date. DBMS table not found

[image]

Same error occurs with a new created geodatabase as well.

Details:

- ArcGIS Server 10.2 on a Linux Machine
- PostgreSQL Geodatabase 9.2 on the same Linux Machine

Comment: Are you upgrading to 10.2 or 10.2.2?  The reason I ask is I tried upgrading to 10.2 once and had so many issues I went back to 10.1.  When 10.2.2 came out I tried again and had success.

Comment: The geodatabase we imported was a 10.1 and we've upgraded it to 10.2 with an ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2 Could this be an issue? The ArcGIS Server is a 10.2. We tried to install the 10.2.2 version and we encountered problems at the authorization process so we came back to 10.2.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to change the [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file to enable for remote connections.
Then you need to register the db with ArcGIS server.
In ArcGIS server you will go to the Site tab, and choose datastore.
Copy your sde connection file to the sever
and point to that connection file.
[image]
[image]

Comment: We've tried this method as well, but at the Import stage after we selected the connection file, the process remains stuck on loading, and at the developer's tools console there is 500 server error.

Comment: We've changed the pg_hba.conf file to enable for remote connections. Still no.

Comment: @Ligia can you register a new geodatabase (10.2) with this method, or does importing the sde connection always cause 500 server error?

Comment: Hello Tom. We've tried registering a new geodatabase and we got the same error as well.

Comment: We've talked to ESRI meanwhile, gave them access to our server and apparently something's wrong with ArcGIS Server's Publishing Tools.They didn't say what exactly. So 10.2 on a Linux may not be a good option.